# Identify a fuse part

Tags: repair, fuses

I'm trying to identify a fuse part that says 125V T 2A on it.

[image]

It seems to be a solid state fuse soldered in place. IE I can't just snap in another replacement fuse in a glass tube like I'm accustomed to. So I need to desolder this one and solder in another. Anyone know where I can order one or if it would be possible to put in a holder for a more regular one?

I'm hoping I'll do better here than with the no-comment public [post on Google+](https://plus.google.com/115300793208454513590/posts/epoMYjf3bXG) I had.

Comment: I don't see anything labeled "125V T 2A".  Sending us a busy picture with lots of parts when you are asking about a particular one doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: There's a giant bunch of text on the left side of the board that talking about the fuse and replacing it.  I'm assuming you're talking about that small black box on the far left.

Comment: Be sure to check the PCB for any other fault. The fuse popping is often an indicator of a bigger problem somewhere else.

Comment: I know it's a busy picture, and yes it took me a while to find it too, but it's right next to where the power comes in on the left. All the caps seem intact, the only other component I'm worried about is the transformer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is a fuse.  Just a normal fuse.

You see the little holes above and below it?  These look to me like they're to take a standard PCB mount fuse socket.

The solid module is easier to auto-assemble than a traditional fuse.  Check the traces under the board - you may well be able to replace it with a standard fuse socket and use a normal fuse.

Comment: To me normal fuses are user serviceable. Yes the traces under it seem to indicate I could mount a wider object on there. Thanks. So the takeaway here is that I don't order one of these totally sealed fuses to mount in the same spot, but rather remove the fuse and put in a more easily obtained one.

Answer (score 3):

The "T" indicates it is a time delay type fuse. 125 volts @ 2 Amps, time delay.